# is.numeric vs. is.integer vs. is.wholenumber - what's the difference?

Tags: r, class, numbers, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column "episode_number" containing alpha-numeric values. I wanted to keep only the rows containing only numeric values in episode_number - no alpha-numeric / punctuation etc.

I used this retain only numeric rows:

`df <- df[!(grepl("[a-zA-Z]", df$episode_number)), ]
df <- df[!(grepl("[[:punct:]]", df$episode_number)), ]`

Next, I wanted to convert the `class` of the column from character to numeric. At first i tried:

`df$episode_number <- as.numeric(df$episode_number)`

Got error: `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Then i did:

`as.numeric(as.character(df$episode_number))` and it worked.

Not being sure whether in fact all values were numeric, I tried to check using: 
`is.integer(df$episode_number)` .

I got `[1] FALSE`.

Being very anxious now, I tried to check whether it passes the whole number test - it did ! There are no exceptions between positive integers & whole numbers - I'm confused ! Funnily enough - while typing this, it also struck me to do:

`as.integer(as.character(df$episode_number))`

`is.integer(df$episode_number)`

guess what? `[1] TRUE`

Here's my sample data. Can anyone explain this quirk of `R`? 
1) Why the type double error?
2) Why is whole number not positive integer? 
3) Why does as.numeric not work and `as.numeric(as.character(x))` work?

`> df
   material_type material material.1 content_identifier_description episode_number
1           ZOR3 30022517   10002178                        Episode             2A
2           ZOR3 30022518   10002178                        Episode             2B
3           ZOR3 30022519   10002178                        Episode             3A
4           ZOR3 30022520   10002178                        Episode             3B
5           ZOR3 30022521   10002178                        Episode             4A
6           ZOR3 30022522   10002514                        Episode            101
7           ZOR3 30022523   10002178                        Episode             4B
8           ZOR3 30022544   10004726                        Episode            201
9           ZOR3 30022545   10004726                        Episode            202
10          ZOR3 30022546   10004726                        Episode            203`

Comment: Show the output from `str(df)`, preferably before you started processing it.

Comment: the warning and details under `?factor` might answer some of these questions. is.wholenumber is not a base r function

Comment: Also note that it is documented in `help(is.integer)` that `is.integer(x)` should not be used to test that `x` contains integer values.  `typeof()` will tell the truth.

Comment: And `as.character()` works because you can call it on a list, although it's not advisable as the result will not be what you expect.  It basically deparses the `...` expressions in `list()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if I think to simple but I give it a try.

At first: How did you define your function is.wholenumber or where did you get it from? It does not seem to be a standard R function.

**To question 2 (Why is whole number not positive integer?):** With *whole number* you mean that the value of your variable looks like a whole number? Thus, you do not speak about a data type but about the value? You have to distinguish between both as the following example shows.

```
# define two variable
a = 3
b = as.integer(3)
# test if the variables are integers
is.integer(a)
is.integer(b)
# test which data type the variables have
storage.mode(a)
storage.mode(b)
```

In this example, the variable *a* and *b* both take the value 3 which is a whole number. The data type of *a* is not integer while that of *b* is. The common data type for variables containing numbers is *numeric*. If you want your variable to be an integer your have to declare it explicitly.

**To question 1 (Why the type double error?):** Please try to organise you data a bit clearer or give a shorter example, the next time.

```
# define a data frame
f1 = data.frame(array(1:12, dim = c(3,4)))
# convert the last column into a double array
d1 = as.numeric(f1$X4)
# works fine!

# now we modify one element
f1[2,4] = '2A'
# and remove it
f2 = f1[!grepl('A',f1$X4), ]
# convert the remaining data into a double array
d2 = as.numeric(f2$X4)
# works also fine
# also this
f2$X4 <- as.numeric(f2$X4)
# works fine

# The error message can only be reproduced if you write
as.numeric(f2)
```

Thus, are you sure, that you wrote this?

```
df$episode_number <- as.numeric(df$episode_number)
```

Comment: `d1 = as.numeric(f1)` actually returns an error. Also please see my comment above about using `is.integer()` to test for integer type.  You also shouldn't use `storage.mode()`, but rather `typeof(x)` to return the data type of `x`

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I didn't know about the difference between `storage.mode()` and `typeof()`. `as.numeric(f1)` was a typo. I corrected it.